# Program for approximating pi

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question asks to write a program that approximates pi using the forumla pi = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + .....

I have to prompt the user for the number of terms in the series, and the calculate the approximation. This is the program I tried

```
import math

def main():

     dummy = 4.0
     term = 0.0
     n = 0.0

     print("This program approximates the value of pi")
     n = eval(input("Enter the number of terms you want in the approximation: ")


     for i in range(1, n+1)
              term = 4/(2n+1)
              dummy = dummy + ((-1)**n) * term

     print("The approximation is ", dummy)
     print("The difference between pi and the approximation is ", math.sqrt((math.pi - dummy)**2))
```

However, when I try to run it I get the error message "Invalid syntax" and the variable "term" is highlighted in red.

Comment: Not that it affects your code, but the last line in your script isn't the proper way to display the difference between two values. A percent difference would be better to represent: (pi - dummy)/ ((pi+dummy)/2))*100. Assuming dummy < pi. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the colon at the end of this line:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
                      ^ missing
```

Whenever you get a syntax error on a line that looks correct, try looking at the line *before* the error to see if *that's* correct.

You also forgot the `)` at the end of this line:

```
     n = eval(input("Enter the number of terms you want in the approximation: ")
```

Comment: I put the colon but it says again invalid syntax and this time it highlights the colon in red :(

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, but is there something wrong with my math? I tried 10 terms and 1000 terms and the approximation got worse

Answer (score 2):

Missing operator `*` here:

```
term = 4/(2n+1)
```

change to

```
term = 4/(2*n+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss ":" at the end of the for statement:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
          term = 4/(2*n+1)
          dummy = dummy + ((-1)**n) * term
```